# Android Koin NoBeanDefFoundException only in release version of app

Tags: android, koin

In Debug version it is working fine, but fails on Release version. I guess it is related to Proguard rules.

```
// Koin
implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:1.0.2'
implementation 'org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:1.0.2'
```

Modules:

```
val appModule = module {
    viewModel<IntroVM>()
}


val dataModule = module {
    single { NetworkManager(androidContext().applicationContext) }
    single { LocalFileManager(androidContext().applicationContext) }
    single { ApiModel(get()) }
```

Class definitions:

```
class ApiModel(val networkManager: NetworkManager){}

class LocalFileManager(private var appContext: Context) {}

class NetworkManager(private var appContext: Context) {}

class IntroVM(var apiModel: ApiModel) : CommonVM() {
```

Koin init:

```
startKoin(this, listOf(appModule, dataModule))
```

Proguard rules:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
}
```

StackTrace:

```
Error while resolving instance for class 'com...viewModels.auth.b' -      
error: org.koin.error.BeanInstanceCreationException:
Can't create definition for 'Factory [name='b',class='com..viewModels.auth.b', binds~(androidx.lifecycle.r)]' due to error :'binds~(androidx.lifecycle.r)]
No constructor found for class 'class com...viewModels.auth.b'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/387)  issue provided needed solution

Answer (score 0):

> As you are using androidX
>   Use below library of viewmodel for koin

```
implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:1.0.2'
```

Comment: unfortunately, still having this error. After replacing libraries, I needed to add this import: "import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.experimental.builder.viewModel"